# How do I install VNC server in a Cubic enviroment?

Tags: tightvncserver

Everytime I install a VNC Server in Cubic it gives me an error

```
root@cubic:/usr/share/backgrounds# vncserver
^C
=================== tail /root/.vnc/cubic:5901.log ===================
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
======================================================================

vncserver: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc exited with status 1, please look into '/root/.vnc/cubic:5901.log' to determine the reason! -2
root@cubic:/usr/share/backgrounds#
```